# display value on checkbox after submit

Tags: php, html

i have a php file like this

```
    <form action='#' method='POST'>
    <p>
        <input type='checkbox' name='interest[]' value="music">music
        <input type='checkbox' name='interest[]' value="reading book">reading book
        <input type='checkbox' name='interest[]' value="coding">coding

    </p>
<input type='submit' name='send'><br/>
    </form>
```

i tried to foreach loop to output the selected values. However it always output "Array";

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $keys =>$values)
{
    echo $values."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: yes since the checkbox name is array.. you should do as `foreach($_POST["interest"] as $keys =>$values)`

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` and you will get to know the structure easily

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST))
{
    foreach($_POST as $keys1 =>$values1)
    {
       if (count($values1) > 0)
       {
         foreach($values1 as $keys2 =>$values2)
         {
           echo $values2."<br/>";
         }
       }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: for any variable except empty array `count` will be greater than 0. Even for a `false`